# UIButton titleLabel number of lines working fine on iOS5 but not on iOS4.3

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I am setting **numberOfLines** for **titleLabel** of `UIButton` :

```
btnMailAddress.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
```

In **iOS5** device the text is being displayed in 3 lines but in **iOS4.3** device the text is fitting in 1 line only.

Comment: can put some more code ?

Comment: This was probably missing an [mcve] and is thus unanswerable now, because of its age.

Answer (score 0):

try with setting it zero.

```
btnMailAddress.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

From `UILabel` documentation for the property `numberOfLines`.

> For using as many lines as needed, set the value of this property to 0.

Comment: @Nitish : Could check the height for the Label.

Comment: It is working fine in ios5. Perhaps it is not an issue of label height.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `lineBreakMode` property of UIButton's `titleLabel` to `UILineBreakModeWordWrap`.

```
btnMailAddress.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

Hope this helps you.